# Start new clean Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, state

Sometimes the OS might kill your activity and save its state and restore it again. I set a viewPager with PagerAdapter to my activity and I want to create a new instance with new instance of adpater and not from any restored state.

This is how I start my activity:

```
Intent intent = PicturActivity.Builder(getContext(), Tools.APPLICATION, position);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_GALERY);
```

In PictureActivity:

```
public static Intent Builder(@NonNull Context context, @Tools.ObjectLocation int listLocation, int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PictureActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_EXTRA_POSITION, position);
        return intent;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can startActivity like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {

    holder.setClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PictureActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_EXTRA_POSITION, position);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either **overrride** this callback.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
}
```

and don't call the **super** class method.

**or**

```
<activity
    android:name=". PictureActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
</activity>
```

Comment: I already put log to check savedInstanceState and it is always null. But will try this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need to do is set the flag.  I think your options are

```
startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE_GALERY,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
```

or

```
startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE_GALERY,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
```

Comment: In the documentation it says that Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK will restore old task if it does exist. And this is what I want to avoid.

Comment: you're right, I updated. i think those two options might help

Comment: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK   can only be used in conjunction with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, for Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY this flag removes activity from stack so if we want to come back to activity it won't be possible. It is not what I want to do. If we start the activity it should be from new start,